# GADT in polymorphic function

Tags: haskell, gadt

I have a problem with a function which I want to make very polymorphic.
I would like to integrate functions, either analytically or numerically. When integrating analytically I provide the result.
In the numeric case I would like to use various methods, for now, the tanhsinh routine from [tanhsinh](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/integration-0.2.1/docs/Numeric-Integration-TanhSinh.html).
I also want to learn more about gadts, so I tried to find a solution using them.

So far I have the following:

```
import qualified Data.VectorSpace as DV
import Numeric.Integration.TanhSinh

data IntegrationType a b  where
      MkAnalytic :: (DV.AdditiveGroup b) =>  (c -> b) -> c -> c -> IntegrationType Analytic b
      MkNumeric ::  NumericType  -> IntegrationType  Numeric [Result]

data Analytic = Analytic
data Numeric = Numeric
data Method = Trapez | Simpson
data IntBounds = Closed | NegInfPosInf | ZeroInf

data NumericType = MkSingleCoreTanhSinh  IntBounds Method  (Double -> Double)  Double Double
              | MkParallelTanhSinhExplicit IntBounds (Strategy [Double])  Method  (Double -> Double)  Double  Double
              | MkParallelTanhSinh IntBounds  Method  (Double -> Double)  Double  Double 

integrate :: IntegrationType a b -> b
integrate (MkAnalytic f l h) = f h DV.^-^ f l
integrate (MkNumeric (MkSingleCoreTanhSinh Closed Trapez f l h )) =  trap f l h
integrate (MkNumeric (MkSingleCoreTanhSinh Closed Simpson f l h )) =  simpson f l h
```

This code compiles , because I expicitly state in the constructor MkNumeric that the type variable b is

```
[Result]
```

Why do I have to do this? Can I not leave the type variable b as in

```
data IntegrationType a b  where
     MkNumeric ::  NumericType  -> IntegrationType  Numeric b
```

When I do this I get an error:

> ```
> Could not deduce (b ~ [Result])
> from the context (a ~ Numeric)
>   bound by a pattern with constructor
>              MkNumeric :: forall b. NumericType -> IntegrationType Numeric b,
>            in an equation for `integrate'
>   at test-classes-new-programm.hs:139:12-64
>   `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
>       the type signature for integrate :: IntegrationType a b -> b
>       at test-classes-new-programm.hs:137:14
> Relevant bindings include
>   integrate :: IntegrationType a b -> b
>     (bound at test-classes-new-programm.hs:138:1)
> In the expression: trap f l h
> In an equation for `integrate':
>     integrate (MkNumeric (MkSingleCoreTanhSinh Closed Trapez f l h))
>       = trap f l h
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type

```
integrate :: IntegrationType a b -> b
```

says that, for *any* `a` and `b` of my choice, if I call `integrate` with a value of type `IntegrationType a b`, I will get back a value of type `b`. When you define

```
MkNumeric ::  NumericType -> IntegrationType Numeric b
```

you let whoever applies the constructor decide what `b` is. So I could use `MkNumeric` to manufacture a value of, say, type `IntegrationType Numeric Int`. But your `integrate` knows how to produce `[Result]`, not `Int`.

In the *working* code, as soon as `integrate` "opens up the evidence box" by matching `MkNumeric`, it learns that `b ~ [Result]` and therefore it can return something of that type.

Comment: Okay, I can understand this. But what if I want to not only return a `[Result]` but maybe also a pair of results like `([Result],[Result])`. Basically I want to be able to return a set of types with my `integrate` function. This is what I thought would have been possible by just saying `MkNumeric ::  NumericType -> IntegrationType Numeric b`

Comment: @TheMADMAN, the big question is what you can do with the results once you have them. In a fully dependently typed language, you can make the result type depend in arbitrary ways on the input values, but using the result requires proving that it has the type you need (this mechanism seems to be useful mostly for things in the nature of metaprogramming). In Haskell, we can't do this; the result type can't depend on the input value.